# Proving a simple inequality with closure under multiplication

Tags: inequality

Suppose we have inequalities $0≤a<b$ and $0≤c<d$ prove
$$ac<bd$$
using closure under multiplication, as if $x>0$ and $y>0$ then $xy>0$.

Comment: What have you tried? Hint: multiply the first inequality, $0\leq a<b$ by $c$, and then multiply the second inequality, $0\leq c<d$, by $b$.

Comment: What I tried was: (b-a)(d-c) is more than 0 because of the closure, but I couldnt think of how to simplify it, as it gave bd-bc-ad+ac.

Comment: Try to do it in two steps: $b-a>0\Rightarrow (b-a)c>0\Rightarrow bc>ac$. Now one more step.

Comment: Oh so you would go $(b-a)c+b(d-c)>0$ to leave you with $bd-ac$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$bd-ac = bd-bc+bc-ac=b(d-c)+(b-a)c>0+0=0$$